# Changing Text Size of Code on GitHub

Tags: github

Is there a way to change the text size when viewing code listings or diffs on Github? When using a widescreen, there is a ton of unused landscape on both sides of the window when viewing code. It would be great to be able to make that window wider, or make the text size used for the code smaller, so more code could be displayed horizontally.

Yes, yes, I know... tell the developer not to code with such long lines and/or split the lines so they're more readable.

Still, any way to have it show more code?

Comment: Credit given for pointing me in the direction of user stylesheets, which helped solve the problem. There is a Chrome extension named Stylish, that allows for easy user stylesheet manipulation, and they have a pre-defined user stylesheet for download named "Github Widescreen" that does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to change the width using the provided settings,  but if you use a browser that supports it, you can add the following rule to the user.css file to make *.github.com wider:

```
.container {
    width: 90% !important;
}
```